# Elements quit responding to visibility changes after switching fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am creating an app that holds a recyclerview in a fragment and the main activity uses a bottom navigation bar to switch fragments. In my main fragment, when a recyclerview item is long clicked, an appbar appears with some buttons and checkboxes. When I press the back button, I would like to hide their visibility to return the fragment to its default state.

My issue is that after first starting the app, the items appear from the long click and then hide when the back button is pressed as it should. If I switch to another fragment, and then switch back, the back button still responds but the elements no longer respond to visibility changes.

This is my onBackPressed() function in my MainActivity.kt:

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
override fun onBackPressed() {

    btnDelete.visibility = View.GONE
    btnDelete.isVisible = false

    radioButton.visibility = View.GONE
    radioButton.isVisible = false

    constrain.visibility = View.GONE
    constrain.isVisible = false

    radioButton.isChecked = false
    radioButton.isSelected = false

    fabButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    fabButton.isVisible = true

    (recyclerView_main.adapter as NoteAdapter).hideItems()
}
```

This is my method of switching fragments in my MainActivity.kt:

```
 if(savedInstanceState == null){
        this.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frag_container, selectedFragment).commit()

    }
    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
        for (i in 0 until supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount){
            this.supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()

        }


        when(it.itemId){

            R.id.nav_home ->{
                this.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(selectedFragment).commit()
                selectedFragment = HomeFragment()
            }
            R.id.nav_fav ->{
                this.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(selectedFragment).commit()

                selectedFragment = FavoriteFragment()
            }
            R.id.nav_trash ->{
                this.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(selectedFragment).commit()

                selectedFragment = TrashFragment()
            }
        }
        this.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frag_container, selectedFragment).commit()
    true
    }
```

Comment: Are views inside `onBackPressed` inside the fragment? Because currently you're leaking references to old views.

Comment: What is `btnDelete`? Does it belong to a Fragment? If it does, why it is in the Activity?

Comment: btnDelete is a button in the layout for the fragment. I have tried handling its visibility from the fragment but I always get an error saying the button is null.